# Couchbase sync-gateway

Tags: nosql, couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

Recently I've installed couchbase sync-gateway, and i'm having following issues from step one,

1) When doing an initial replication from couchbase to pouchdb through syncgateway, there are excess documents coming through. 
Eg: Having only 3 objects on couchbase bucket but syncgateway returns more than 3 documents.

2) Inconsistent data when using filters

There's no proper document/log why this is happening. Does anyone know why this is? And how to resolve them

Comment: regarding issue 1 - that is sync data generated by the sync-gateway. It is expected and not a problem. As for issue 2, how are you going about filtering?

Answer (score 0):

For issue
1. It is expected behavior from syncgateway. Syncgateway has its own meta information on each documents inserted through syncgateway and some _sync:* documents for its own identification/use. you can ignore these documents.
2. What do you means by insertion of data by filter?

Comment: second half is more likely comment on the OP's post